# Don't escape double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, quotes, double-quotes, uglifyjs

as I found out uglifyJS ignores an escaped double quotes in a single quote string.

```
'test \" + foo + \"'
```

results in

```
'test " + foo + "'
```

This is just a wrong behaviour.

I have a `.js` that I want to minify and this data have to go into a JSON. But the JSON API have to be like this.

```
{
    string: "test \" + foo + \""
}
```

not

```
{
    string: "test " + foo + ""
}
```

Is there a way to configure uglifyJS that it don't ignore `\"`

At the moment I uglify my javascript and replace all my `\"` with placeholders. After this, I do a string replace with all placeholders to get it working.
But then my tests don't work.

**EDIT:** The uglify version of my `Javascript` has to be valid `JSON` and valid `Javascript` as well.

**EDIT:** As requested, a part of the real example. This code has to be uglified and then put into a JSON.

```
var privacylink = '#privacyButtonURL#';
link = '<a href=\"' + privacylink + '\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#4398b5; text-decoration:underline;\">hear</a>';
```

The uglify version would be

```
var a="#privacyButtonURL#", b='<a href="'+a+'" target="_blank" style="color:#4398b5; text-decoration:underline;">hear</a>'
```

This would not work.

```
JSON.stringify('var a="#privacyButtonURL#", b='<a href="'+a+'" target="_blank" style="color:#4398b5; text-decoration:underline;">hear</a>'')
```

Comment: "This is just a wrong behaviour" — It isn't. In JavaScript, in that context, the two statements mean exactly the same thing. Your problem is that you are depending on specific formatting of JS so that you can build JSON out of it by mashing strings together. Use a proper JSON library instead.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({string: 'test " + foo + "'})`

Comment: That is not the problem. I create dynamically a `.js` that I want to send to my backend. The API of my backend only takes JSON. So I send a valid JSON to it with the `.js` as a string. But in this `.js` string I need escaped double quotes otherwise, it dosesn't work.

Comment: @DK1990 I don't understand, can you give a simple, real example where `{string: JSON.stringify('test " + foo + "')}` doesn't work? It'll give exactly what you want, transform the single quotes into double quotes and escape the double quotes inside. No need to manually add superfluous/illegal escape characters.

Comment: as requested. I added a real example.

Comment: I try to `JSON.stringify` a hole javascript that has to work in the browser. So the `JS` has to be a string in the JSON but valid `JS` in the browser when it is delivered to a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [github issue](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/495) about quote format.

The solution given in the link above is to tell uglify to keep the original quote format:

```
$ echo "console.log(\"foo\",'bar');" | uglifyjs --quotes=1
console.log('foo','bar');

$ echo "console.log(\"foo\",'bar');" | uglifyjs --quotes=2
console.log("foo","bar");

$ echo "console.log(\"foo\",'bar');" | uglifyjs --quotes=3
console.log("foo",'bar');
```

Or with gulp, give the following as parameter to the `uglify.minify()` function:

```
{ output: { quote_style: 3 } }
```

For your specific problem, as I'm not sure it will keep the unnecessary escape characters (in javascript), a solution would be:

- remove all single quotes from the javascript by switching everything to double quotes and escape them where necessary
- uglify the code with the above option
- do `{string: JSON.stringify(code)}`

If your javascript code has to have single quotes for some reason, instead you can replace the double quotes in the generated html in the javascript code by `&#34;` or `&quot;`.

Note that I don't feel that something like `var a = 'abc \" def';` is valid javascript in the first place.

Another thing to look into would be how you include file (it's not mentioned), maybe there's a better way that directly loads the file into a string, on which you can then call `JSON.stringify()`.

**Edit**

If you use a recent javascript engine, you can also use [backquotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`) in your code and replace double or single quotes by them.

**Or**, if there's no `$` nor backquotes in your javascript code, you can simply do:

```
{
    string: JSON.stringify(`uglified javascript code`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
'test \\" + foo + \\"'
```

reference:
http://es5.github.io/#x7.8.4

Comment: When you uglify the javascript with this, it is not valid javascript anymore.